Using Fields in a data extension for intelligence reports dashboard
I have been tasked with creating a custom dashboard (we have intelligence reports advanced in MC) that show the number of opens/clicks, etc. by attributes in a data extension.  For example - I'd like to see the % of clicks from one email send filtered by the top 10 FIRMS.  I know I can see by email domain, but we group them by firm name instead of domain typically.  I'd also like to see the number of "active" subscribers - our definition is someone that has opened at least one email in the past X number of days.  The other filters we would like to use is based on segmentation.  Is there a way to be able to filter off of these in the dashboards by creating custom dimensions and if so, how would I go about doing this? I can't seem to find any documentation on it.
Any help is appreciated!
